# Hibernate query result is empty

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am learning hibernate and made a simple program to read a table from my sql.
The result list that I am getting after executing the query is having size zero even though table has 14 records in it.
I made the show_sql to see the sql logs and I am getting this :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Hibernate: select insurance0_.lngInsuranceId as col_0_0_ from insurance insurance0_
```

I am also attaching code for reference

```
Session session = new Configuration().configure("Hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory().openSession();

    String SQL_QUERY ="from Insurance insurance";
    Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
    System.out.println("size of list is: "+query.list().size());
    List resultList = query.list();

    for (Iterator iterator = resultList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Insurance object = (Insurance) iterator.next();
        System.out.println("insurance name is: "+object.getInsuranceName());
        System.out.println("insurance amount is: "+object.getInvestementAmount());

    }
    session.close();
```

Entity class :

```
public class Insurance {

  private long lngInsuranceId;
  private String insuranceName;
  private int investementAmount;
  private Date investementDate;
public long getLngInsuranceId() {
    return lngInsuranceId;
}
public void setLngInsuranceId(long lngInsuranceId) {
    this.lngInsuranceId = lngInsuranceId;
}
public String getInsuranceName() {
    return insuranceName;
}
public void setInsuranceName(String insuranceName) {
    this.insuranceName = insuranceName;
}
public int getInvestementAmount() {
    return investementAmount;
}
public void setInvestementAmount(int investementAmount) {
    this.investementAmount = investementAmount;
}
public Date getInvestementDate() {
    return investementDate;
}
public void setInvestementDate(Date investementDate) {
    this.investementDate = investementDate;
}
```

}

Please help as I am not able to zero in this issue?

Comment: can you post your entity class ?

Comment: Are you sure you are pointing to right Database?

Comment: To make sure I am pointing to right DB. I inserted a new record using hibernate. and it worked correctly

Comment: whats the query hibernate generated ,while you inserting a record ?

Comment: Hibernate: select max(lngInsuranceId) from insurance
Hibernate: insert into insurance (insurance_name, invested_amount, investement_date, lngInsuranceId) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: One more thing that is weird is that every time I create a record from Hibernate. It removes the existing record and only one record is left.

Comment: to fix that issue , set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update in your hibernate.cfg.xml :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by beginning a transaction before creating query and committing after printing data. I don't know why I need to have a transaction to query the database.

Comment: thanks, i added `session.beginTransaction().commit()` before creating the query and that resolved the problem. i do not ask why, i tend to don't use hibernate anymore in future projects

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem with test:

```
@Test
public void readMessage() {
    try (Session session = factory.openSession()) {
        List<Message> list = session.createQuery("from Message", Message.class).list();
        assertEquals(list.size() > 3, true);
    }
}
```

use: `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

Reference: [What are the possible values of the Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto configuration and what do they do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wha)